# conditional update using HQL

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

I'm trying to update some rows of my database using the following script which works pretty fine :

```
update DOS
set NAMEDOS=:name,
AGEDOS=:age,
WEIGHTDOS=:weight
where CODEDOS=:code
```

My problem is the following, sometimes the weight can be empty or null, so i have to just set the other properties.

I have tried to proceed like this, but it doesn't seems to work:

```
update DOS
set NAMEDOS=:name,
AGEDOS=:age,
WEIGHTDOS= (case when weight is not null then :weight else :WEIGHTDOS end),
where CODEDOS=:code
```

Can you help me please.

Comment: waht is the exception you get?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try switching the brackets a bit and i think that `:WEIGHTDOS` should be without the double dots as its the direct column name not a parameter:

```
update DOS
    set NAMEDOS=:name,
    AGEDOS=:age,
    WEIGHTDOS= case when (:weight is not null) then :weight 
                  else WEIGHTDOS 
               end,
    where CODEDOS=:code
```

Comment: when weight has a value, the script turn well, but when trying with null value, i get 

java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected BiNARYgot CHAR

Comment: What is the column type of WEIGHTDOS?

Comment: the column WEIGHTDOS is a : String

Comment: more exactly, it's a  VARCHAR2()

Comment: it turns out your answer was very helpfull, the problem was in the way i was building the request :
I should have used 
      Query q =getSession().createQuery();
      q.setString("weight ", weight);   
instead of :
       Query q =getSession().createQuery();
      q.setParameter("weight ", weight);

Comment: Great! Glad i could help

Comment: thank you so much, i don't have enough reputation credit to vote for your answer.